# NSubstitute's Received(count) is always green (when mocking concrete class)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Edit: During the work I further isolated, that the issue is only when mocking concrete class, not interface, so I am editing the title.

**Context**

It seems NSubstitute's .Received(...) is always green regardless if any call happened at all. 
To isolate this issue, I've created a two line unit test, and actually *do not call anything*, still checking for got 10 calls is green:

```
 var processor = Substitute.For<Processor>();
 processor.Received(10).Process(Arg.Any<MyType>()); // this is green (do not throws)
```

Using latest stable 3.1.0

**Question**

Am I missing something? If yes, what is the correct way to check against a specific number of calls? (the bad news that if this is a bug, our projects are full of potentially false greens.

Comment: When I run your sample I got: `NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive exactly 10 calls matching: Process(any String). Actually received no matching calls`

Comment: @Fabio thanks for trying, I double checked, I do not get exception. Running this very same two lines. Do you mock a concrete class or interface? I've just isolated, that using interface the bug is not there. Using a concrete class it is there. I also checked the concrete class use case: the Castle proxy is in effect.

Comment: What's more weird: The concrete class's concrete method is actually called both in the Arrange phase ! (second line in the code) both later during the Act, when the sut uses the mock. Both are completely against the whole concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSubstitute will only work with virtual members on class. From [Creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/):

> *Warning:* Substituting for classes can have some nasty side-effects. For starters, NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the class, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute! If you try to substitute for your class that formats your hard drive in the constructor or in a non-virtual property setter then you’re asking for trouble. If possible, stick to substituting interfaces.

This means you can only use `.Received()`, `When()..Do()` and `.Returns` on members marked virtual. When substituting for an interface, all members will work fine.

Comment: Confirmed this is my case. Thanks, this explains the execute thing. But the chapter you are referring does not mention that Received is completely unusable. IMHO silently swallowing this fact at runtime is not a good practice, It should throw an exception when trying to instrument / arrange or assert on a non virtual method, it would spare time instead of advertising "you can format your C drive" in the docs

Comment: @g.pickardou Unfortunately this isn't possible with NSubstitute's syntax (how will `Received()` know which member is going to be called _after_ it?). In more positive news, work is underway on some [Roslyn analysers to detect these cases](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute.Analyzers). Feel free to try it out, and please contribute if you have the time! :)

Comment: @g.pickardou I've sent a PR for the docs (https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/pull/410). If you get a chance please take a look at the diff and let me know if that would have helped in this case.